# Different vector lengths when using NA

Tags: r

I'm getting interesting results from the following and am not sure why.

```
match(3, 1:2)
```

returns `NA`

```
c(1, 3)[NA]
```

returns `NA NA`

```
c(1, 3)[match(3, 1:2)]
```

returns `NA`

What's going on here? Why are the second and third results different lengths? Intuitively, substituting `match(3, 1:2)` with its result `NA` should come up with the same result but it doesn't. What triggers that?

Comment: `match`. returns the index of the first match.  In the first case, there is no match and byd efault `nomatch = NA`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I was wondering why the lengths are different

Comment: Due to recycling

Answer (score 2):

There is recycling effect.  In the case of `match`, if there is no matches, by default `nomatch = NA_integer`

```
c(1, 3)[match(3, 1:2)]
#[1] NA
```

while the OP used a `NA_logical_` while not specifying the type and it just recycles the `NA` to the `length` of the vector i.e. 2.  If we do the type conversion, will get the same output

```
c(1, 3)[as.logical(match(3, 1:2))]
#[1] NA NA
```

Same thing can be replicated in reverse

```
c(1, 3)[NA_integer_]
#[1] NA
```

The reason is mentioned in `?NA`

> NA is a logical constant of length 1 which contains a missing value indicator. NA can be coerced to any other vector type except raw. There are also constants NA_integer_, NA_real_, NA_complex_ and NA_character_ of the other atomic vector types which support missing values: all of these are reserved words in the R language.
>
> Logical computations treat NA as a missing TRUE/FALSE value, and so may return TRUE or FALSE if the expression does not depend on the NA operand.

Comment: The different datatype was what I was missing, thank you.